# Function by using Recursion?

Tags: c#, c++

I want to make a function which will display numbers starting from 1 to 100 and 100 to 1 
I am confused that how i can do this using Recursion?

I dont want to do this using any other loop.
Please provide me hint and ignore my way of asking because i am new in c++ and c#.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What are you confused about? What are you stuck on? Please post your current code.

Comment: 1-100 and 100-1 with the same function?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes with same function

Comment: @RoyDictus i am trying to learn :)

Comment: So, first up to 100 and then down to 1 again? And you must do this assignment in C# or C++?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but unless you're doing this to learn how to use recursion, you **should** use a loop. Recursion will generally be slower, less readable, and has the risk of causing a stack overflow. Recursion is very rare in real, production code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void Print100(int n)
{
   if (n > 100)
   {
       Console.WriteLine();  // cosmetic
       return;               // stop recursing
   }

   Console.WriteLine(n);     // 1-100
   Print100(n+1);            // recurse
   Console.WriteLine(n);     // 100-1, on the way out
}


void Main()
{
    Print100(1);
}
```

Comment: very little coding with big logic and i am unable to understand that how the values will return from 100 to 1 because there is no code for this ??

Comment: This shows how the stack and recursion work. Probably the aim of the exercise. Q: When the empty `WriteLine()` executes, how many variables called `n` are in memory? A: 101. At the turning point, all methods are still 'active', waiting to execute their 2nd `WriteLine(n)`.

Comment: Very clever, although it doesn't print `100` at the top.

Comment: @Rawling - there was a little off-by-one error but I fixed that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes  i understand now after study the main logic whole the night :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

for printing numbers from 1 to 100

```
private void number(int n)
        {
            if (n == 100)
                return;
            Response.Write(n + "<br/>");
            number(n + 1);
        }
```

Call:

```
number(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do a recursive for:

```
public static void For<T>(
    T initializer,
    Func<T, bool> condition,
    Func<T, T> iterator,
    Action<T> action)
{
    if (!condition(initializer)) return;
    action(initializer);
    For(iterator(initializer), condition, iterator, action);
}
```

One to one hundred:

```
For(1, i => i <= 100, i => i + 1, i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

One hundred to one left as an exercise.

Comment: Admittedly I've just fixed some errors, but how is this not recursive?

Comment: @TravisJ I wouldn't recommend ever _using_ it, but I like the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You write a function that takes two parameters, basically: the current number and the direction (up or down). Then you output that number, increase or decrease it and call the same function again, until you have reached 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function in c++:

```
    void printNumbers(int number)
    {
       if (i >= 1) 
       {
          // 100 --> 1
          cout << number << " ";
          printNumbers(i-1);
          // 1 --> 100
          cout << number << " ";
       }
    }
```

Call your function with printNumbers(100)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

c#

```
public void recurseInts( int start, int finish ){
 if( start > finish ) return;
 Console.WriteLine(start);
 Console.WriteLine(finish - start);
 recurseInts(start + 1 , finish);
}

recurseInts(0,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void recur(int start, int end,bool asc){
    cout << start << endl;
    if(!asc && start==0)return;
    if(start == end) asc = false;
    asc?start++:start--;
    recur(start, end, asc);
}

int main(){
    recur(0, 100,true);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code and submit your assignment:

```
class Program
{

    public static bool forward = false;
    public static bool stop = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintNumbers(0);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void PrintNumbers(int i)
    {
        if (i <= 100 && !forward)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            if (i == 100)
            {
                forward = true;
            }
            PrintNumbers(i + 1);

        }
        if (i >= 0  && i < 100 && forward && !stop)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(i);

            PrintNumbers(i - 1);
            if (i==0)
            {
                stop = true;
            }

        }

    }
}
```