# Recursion Code Error in c#?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am New in c# so please ignore my way of asking
i am much confused that my function of recursion is correct but code is showing error.
Please help

here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
      void Print100(int n)
        {
            if (n >= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();  
                return;               
            }

            Console.WriteLine(n);   
            Print100(n + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(n);  

}

        }
    }
}
```

I have created a function to display 1-100 and 100-1 integers by using recursion.

Comment: You can't create nested functions in C# - move `Print100` out of your `Main` method.

Comment: Your code will not even compile.  Come back when you have code that will compile.  There isn't any reason for this function to be recursive.

Comment: So you got the recursive function almost 2 hours ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008846/function-by-using-recursion) and now you are asking about putting the same function in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to declare one method inside another. That's not valid in C#. You *could* use an anonymous function, but it would be relatively painful. Just move the `Print100` method (and ideally rename it at the same time) outside `Main`, and *call* it from `Main`.

Comment: yes you are right :) now i corrected it and it is working.

Comment: i wonder why my question goes vote down as after having your attention and answer?

Answer (score 4):

You have method inside a method. Extract the `Print100` method outside of the Main method. Then make a call to `Print100` method from your `Main` function.

Answer (score 2):

Write your `Print100` code out side the void main block and call it from the Void Main block. You did the wrong placing of code parts.